# Why is my javascript variable not being used properly in my function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a site that may include multiple jQuery slideshows on a single plage.  The 3rd party slideshow code that I'm using requires that each slideshow has a unique ID that's used in the javascript and div that houses the images.

Currently I'm generating a random number in the  of the page:

```
var postID = ((Math.random() * 1e6) | 0);)
```

and within each slideshow post, I'm incrementing postID by 1:

```
postID++;
```

to avoid duplicate numbers.  However, it appears that it is not using the correct postID in the javascript function:

```
$(function() {$("#" + postID).webwidget_slideshow_dot({...)})}
```

Here's a link to the site: http://mobilegamepatterns.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We need a bit more than this.  As far as I can tell, your postID is never used in the page.

Comment: Here: `((Math.random() * 1e6) | 0);)`, why is the `;` not at the end of the statement?

Comment: Please don't just start a new question because of a small problem with a previous one you've asked. If you are running into problems with code given to you in a previously posted question, comment on that post and the people will refine there answer to better help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have this block in your code twice:

```
$("#" + postID).webwidget_slideshow_dot({
                    slideshow_time_interval: '',
                    slideshow_window_width: '320',
                    slideshow_window_height: '480',
                    slideshow_title_color: '#17CCCC',
                    soldeshow_foreColor: '#000',
                    directory: 'http://mobilegamepatterns.s3.amazonaws.com/images/'
                });
```

I think that you think that because of where they are positioned in your page that one will run with the first ID and one will run with the second. But actually, they will both run with the second. They will both be run after the DOM is ready and they will both use the current value of postID. Since you are changing postID while the page is loading it will be whatever it is after the last postID++.

If you are going to write your page this way, you need to not run this code onReady, but instead run it immediately after you assign the div the new ID.

You could be cleaner and do it all on page load without using the IDs at all.

```
$(function() {
    var slideShowDivs = $('.webwidget_slideshow_dot');
        $.each(slideShowDivs, function(i, currentDiv) {

              $(currentDiv).webwidget_slideshow_dot({
                    slideshow_time_interval: '',
                    slideshow_window_width: '320',
                    slideshow_window_height: '480',
                    slideshow_title_color: '#17CCCC',
                    soldeshow_foreColor: '#000',
                    directory: 'http://mobilegamepatterns.s3.amazonaws.com/images/'
               });
        }
  });
```

NOTE: The above code is untested. It might have syntax errors in it.